# for-loop and getchar() in C

Tags: c, for-loop, getchar

Why does the code get the empty data directly in even times? I have no idea what is going on.
Thank you very much.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #pragma warning(disable : 4996) 
    
    void main() {
        
        int f, a = 10, b = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            char ch;
            ch = getchar();
            printf("ch = %c\n", ch);
            switch (ch)
            {
                case '+': f = a + b; printf("f = %d\n", f); break;
                case '−': f = a - b; printf("f = %d\n", f); break;
                case '*': f = a * b; printf("f = %d\n", f); break;
                case '/': f = a / b; printf("f = %d\n", f); break;
                default: printf("invalid operator\n"); 
            }
    
        }
    
    }
```

[image]

If I input one operator，it loops two time. And the second time is the empty input.

Comment: Please explain in detail what's not working, and what the expected result is

Comment: Each time I input any operator, it will display the following information.
"ch =

invalid operator"

Comment: Other notes: 1)Use `int main(void)` 2)`ch` should be an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you typed `a` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The first call to `getchar()` returns `a` but the newline is still left in the input stream. The next call to `getchar()` returns the newline without waiting for your input.

There are many ways to take care of this problem. One of the simplest ways is to ignore the rest of the line after the call to `getchar()`.

```
ch = getchar();

// Ignore the rest of the line.
int ignoreChar;
while ( (ignoreChar = getchar()) != '\n' && ignoreChar != EOF );
```

You can wrap that in a function.

```
void ignoreLine(FILE* in)
{
   int ch;
   while ( (ch = fgetc(in)) != '\n' && ch != EOF );
}
```

and use

```
ch = getchar();

// Ignore the rest of the line.
ignoreLine(stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change a lot in your code, I suggest just insert another `getchar` at the end of for loop to consume '\n':

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996) 

void main() {

    int f, a = 10, b = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        char ch;
        ch = getchar();
        printf("ch = %c\n", ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
            case '+': f = a + b; printf("f = %d\n", f); break;
            case '−': f = a - b; printf("f = %d\n", f); break;
            case '*': f = a * b; printf("f = %d\n", f); break;
            case '/': f = a / b; printf("f = %d\n", f); break;
            default: printf("invalid operator\n"); 
        }
        getchar();

    }

}
```